# Как при помощи телеграмм-бота блокировать участника группы командой /ban но не навсегда?

Tags: python, aiogram

Какой код написать на питоне используя aiogram чтобы забанить человека через /ban ответом на его сообщение, но чтобы бан был на, к примеру, 2 часа. В ban_chat_member есть параметр until_date но работает он только в супергруппах или публичных канал, а у меня группа частная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делать базу данных через sql, в которой будут собираться параметры пользователей твоего бота. А дальше через изменение параметров этой базы банить пользователя. Вот что то подобное https://habr.com/ru/articles/599199/